# Distance of a gps point to a polyline

Tags: gps, distance, point, polyline

I would like to find any algorithm available to solve the problem of calculating the distance from a gps point to a polyline(set of gps points).

Thanking you in advance,
Adam

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try Shapely geometry library:

```
point = somePoint;
linestring = someLineString;

dist = point.distance(linestring);  // cartesian distance, not great circle distance!
```

It is usually very straightforward to create these objects from some other type or collection.

If you need Java (as I commented below), most probably you want to use `DistanceOp` ([docs](http://geos.osgeo.org/doxygen/classgeos_1_1operation_1_1distance_1_1DistanceOp.html)).

Comment: is there any similar library available on Java?

Comment: In the Shapely page, I found this: _Shapely is a Python package for set-theoretic analysis and manipulation of planar features using (via Python’s ctypes module) functions from the well known and widely deployed GEOS library._ http://trac.osgeo.org/geos/

Comment: This library looks really interesting and if i ve understand well i can calculate the distance between two geometries as desired, in the same way with your example. I will test it now.

Comment: Yeah, "distance" is an abstract function defined for every subclass of `Geometry` type. You can "measure" the distance between any two geometries (Points, LineStrings, Rings, Polygons...)

Comment: The resulted distance is not in metres. Can i overcome this? Actually, what am doing am constructing a line string and a point FROM GPS POINTS and then am calculating the distance

Comment: Solved. I have convert lat lon to UTM values and then i ve got the correct distance.

Comment: Nice. Another option would be to use Great Circle Distance (easy to google around), but since you are already using GEOS, converting to UTM seems much better!